# count group by conflict oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, count

For the following query, I got the result below

```
select date, count(sales) 
from table 
where date between to_date('2015-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2015-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD') 
group by date

Date        Count(sales) 
01-SEP-15   480
01-SEP-15   2
01-SEP-15   3
01-SEP-15   2
16-SEP-15   12
16-SEP-15   7
```

It should just give me two rows->  01-SEP-15 and count(sales) as 487.
and 16-SEP-15 and count(sales) as 19
How do I get that?

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle a `date` also contains a time part. Your SQL client hides that from you by not including that in the output. You need to `trunc()` the date column to set the time part to `00:00:00`

```
select trunc(date), count(sales) 
from table 
where date between to_date('2015-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2015-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD') 
group by trunc(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic that you probably intend is more like:

```
select trunc(date), count(sales) 
from table 
where trunc(date) between date '2015-09-01' and date '2015-12-31'
group by trunc(date);
```

However, if you have an index on `date` but not `trunc(date)`, this would more naturally be written for performance as:

```
select trunc(date), count(sales) 
from table 
where date >= date '2015-09-01' and
      date < date '2016-01-01'
group by trunc(date);
```